# How to disable form submit button if text field value is set to a specific value or blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-forms

I've created a **form using Google Docs** which sends data to a google spreadsheet. I've taken the html code and reformatted it to my css/style and it works perfectly. It also displays a custom thankyou page and the only problem I'm facing is that it doesn't validate the data.

So, I'm thinking of **disabling the submit button if the user hasn't entered anything** in the required fields. Or, you could suggest a way to prevent blank form submission?

Currently My form has **2 text fields**, and 4 checkboxes. I require both the text fields, but not the checkboxes. The text fields are currently **populated/cleared with html/script**:

```
value="Your Email or Phone No."
onfocus="if (this.value=='Your Email or Phone No.') this.value='';"
```

I require my form to disable the submit button if no data has been entered.

Here's my full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted) {window.location='thankyou.htm';}"></iframe>
<form action="Google_Form_ID_Here_(removed-for-stackoverflow-post)" method="POST" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
<ol style="padding-left: 0">


<div dir="ltr"><label for="entry_145">Name &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
</label>
<input type="text" name="entry.145" value="Enter Full Name" id="entry_145" dir="auto" aria-required="true" onfocus="if (this.value=='Enter Full Name') this.value='';">
</div>



<div dir="ltr" ><label for="entry_624">Contact Info &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
</label>
<input type="text" name="entry.624" value="Your Email or Phone No." id="entry_624" dir="auto" aria-required="true" onfocus="if (this.value=='Your Email or Phone No.') this.value='';">
</div>


<div align="center">
<div dir="ltr"><label for="entry_755"><br>Checkboxes
</div><br>
<div dir="ltr">Check which of the functions you&#39;ll be attending.</label><br><br>


<table align="center" width="248" height="128" border="0">

  <span>
  <tr>
  <td align="center"><input id="group_418_1" name="entry.418" type="checkbox" value="Event 1"/>
                <label class="vis_hide">Event 1</label></td>
    <td align="center"><input id="group_418_2" name="entry.418" type="checkbox" value="Event 2"/>
                 <label class="vis_hide">Event 2</label></td>
    <td align="center"><input id="group_418_3" name="entry.418" type="checkbox" value="Event 3"/>
                <label class="vis_hide">Event 3</label></td>
    <td align="center"><input id="group_418_4" name="entry.418" type="checkbox" value="Event 4"/>
                <label class="vis_hide">Event 4</label></td>
  </tr>
  </span>
</table>



<input type="hidden" name="draftResponse" value="[]">
<input type="hidden" name="pageHistory" value="0">


<div dir="ltr">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" class="sbutton">
</div></ol></form>
```

Please can someone provide help regarding this? Or a suggestion for alternative to prevent blank submissions or provide a link to the solution? **Can this be done with some jquery script too?**

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

I tried this script but that didn't help too...

```
<script>
$(function () {
// give the <form> the ID "myform" (or whatever you want) before using this code!
var form = $("#myform");

var input1 = $("#entry_145"); //for name
var input2 = $("#entry_624"); //for contact


form.addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
if (input1.val() == "" || input2.val() == "") {
evt.preventDefault();
}
}, false);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it or leave it ,Dirty code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" ></script>
<input type="text" class="req" id="name" />
<input type="text" class="req" id="post" />
<input type="submit" class="btn" id="button" onClick='alert("hi");' disabled/>

<script>
$(function (){
$('.req').change(function(){
    if ($('#name').val() == '' || $('#post').val() == '')
        {
            $('#button').attr('disabled',true);
        }
    else
        {
            $('#button').attr('disabled',false);
        }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: That won't prevent the user from hitting `[Enter]` in the input field.

Comment: That didn't work... I'm thinking of changing onsubmit property to validation and "=true" on completion. : I know what part to change, but don't know how to change it!...: `<form action="Google_Form_ID_Here" method="POST" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">`

Comment: sure as I said you can change it, I have not tested it , :), Warned already, was sleepy that time

Comment: I found the solution on this page: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp ..... Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for client-side "validation":

- Use JavaScript and add a `submit` event listener to your `<form>` tag.
- Add the `required` attributes to your text boxes:

  ```
  <input type="text" required="required" />
  ```

But these won't prevent users with an old browser (when using second option) or computer savvy people who just send the form manually.

You have to perform **server-side validation**, too!

---

Try this for the `change` event listeners:

```
$(function () {
  // give the <form> the ID "myform" (or whatever you want) before using this code!
  var form = $("#myform");

  var input1 = $("#my-input1-name");
  var input2 = $("#my-input2-name");


  form.submit(function (evt) {
    if (input1.val() == "" || input2.val() == "") {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm using identifiers for a Google Docs based form! It doesn't validate after customizing. I tried several jquery plugins for validate but it still sends the data to the spreadsheet, **without** validating! .... How do I add change event listeners and to what? I mean what to change and which event listeners to use?

Comment: @user2377276 I've added an example.

Comment: That didn't help either...Edited the question. ... Also, what do you mean by `change` event listener?

Comment: @user2377276 I'm sorry, I've mixed up jQuery and pure JavaScript/DOM things. The code is now corrected. Please try again. You don't actually need `change` in this case, `submit` should be sufficient.